# inno setup first start Components

Tags: components, inno-setup

I'm a Korean. So English is poor.
I will use inno setup.
but There was a problem.

I want to do 'setup.exe compornet' I want to do first.

```
[Components]
Name: "sybase"; Description: "sybase"; Types: full
Name: "old_NIS"; Description: "old_NIS"; Types: full
Name: "new_NIS"; Description: "new_NIS"; Types: full
Name: "sybase_file"; Description: "sybase_file"; Types: full


[Files]
;sybase 프로그램
Source: "D:\a\setup.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: sybase
;신NIS
Source: "D:\b\*"; DestDir: "D:\b"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Components: new_NIS
;구NIS
Source: "D:\c\*"; DestDir: "C:\c"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Components: old_NIS

;***********sybase 설치후 작업단계*********************;
;sybase 설치후 32bit , 64bit 모두 설치.
Source: "D:\a\*"; DestDir: "C:\sybase"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Components: sybase_file
;system 파일 32bit 64bit 구분설치
Source: "D:\a\*"; DestDir: "C:\Windows\System32"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: not Is64BitInstallMode; Components: sybase_file
Source: "D:\a\*"; DestDir: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: Is64BitInstallMode; Components: sybase_file
;regsvr32 ezftp.ocx 처리하는것.
Source: ..\..\..\Windows\System32\EZFTP.OCX; DestDir: {app}; Flags: regserver; Components: sybase_file
```

Comment: Please format your code as `code` like ~~>  ` + YOUR TEXT + `

Comment: sorry, I did not know how to use it.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you want. What does it mean *"first start Components"*? What does it mean "setup.exe compornet"? Do you want to specify component to install on command-line?

Comment: I made four components. sybase, old_nis, new_nis, sybase_file
I would like to run sybase at first

Comment: Well, see my answer. But I have a feeling that it's not what you need. Don't you really want to run the sybase `setup.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Components are not run. Component is just a grouping for installation files/tasks/etc.

The files/tasks/etc are processed in the order in which they appear in the script.

So if you put files for "sybase" component first, they will be installed first. But you are actually doing that.